# Laravel auth::atempt get only hashed password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created account's in CRM and hashed password in it.

```
$account->password = bcrypt($password);
```

then on my web site I've created some guard and provider:

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'business' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'business'
        ]
    ],

 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Eloquent\Account::class,
        ],
        'business' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Models\Eloquent\BusinessAccounts::class
        ]
    ],
```

and then try to login account with guard business:

```
public function login(BusinessLoginRequest $request)
    {
        $orgNumber = $request->input('orgNumber');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        if(Auth::guard('business')->attempt(['orgNumber' => $orgNumber, 'password' => $password ])) {
                var_dump(\auth('business')->user());
        }

    }
```

and my Model looks like:

```
class BusinessAccounts extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    protected $table = 'business_accounts';

    protected $fillable =
        [
            'orgNumber', 'password'
        ];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

but when I'm trying to login and var_dump user with password which was'nt hashed I have blank screen and when I'm trying to put hashed password from my DB I can see business accounts model.
 What is wrong with my code? 
How I can understand thad Auth::atempt just check the value from login password with db-password and, of course, there are not same. 
I've read many guides and articles but can't find mistake, 
I know that can be simple but I don't see that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `bcrypt` while using `attempt` function. As you already store hashed password in database you need to just compare that password which is done by `attempt` function.

So just remove `bcrypt` and pass as it is

```
$account->password = $password;
```

From [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users)

> If the user is found, the hashed password stored in the database will
>   be compared with the password value passed to the method via the
>   array. You should not hash the password specified as the password
>   value, since the framework will automatically hash the value before
>   comparing it to the hashed password in the database.

Comment: I've used bcrypt only when I save model in DB through CRM. I don't use bcrypt on login